# Regex and no. of occurrences

Tags: regex, repeat

I want it to match a 2-to-15-character string containing only capital/lowercase letters and numbers; hyphens only allowed in-between.

```
/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{0,13}[a-z0-9]$/i
```

Such as: `a-b-c` `ab` `a-b` `a-bcdef-g-h-i`

How do I make sure that no two+ hyphens appear in a row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a negative [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/^(?!.*--)[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,13}[a-z0-9]$/i
```

`(?!.*--)` ensures that it's impossible to match `--` anywhere in the string (without actually consuming any characters in the match).

Also, no need to escape the dash if it's the first or last character in a character class.

If you're not keen on lookaheads with indefinite quantifiers (like Donal Fellows), another way would be

```
/^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]|-(?!-)){0,13}[a-z0-9]$/i
```

`(?:[a-z0-9]|-(?!-)){0,13}` matches either an alphanumeric character or a dash if it's not followed by another dash, repeating up to 13 times.

As for performance (checked in Python 3.2.2):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='r.match("a--bcdefghijklmop-qrstuvwxyz")', 
... setup='import re; r=re.compile(r"^(?!.*--)[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,13}[a-z0-9]$")')
0.699529247317531
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='r.match("a--bcdefghijklmop-qrstuvwxyz")', 
... setup='import re; r=re.compile(r"^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]|-(?!-)){0,13}[a-z0-9]$")')
0.6518945164968741
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='r.match("a-bcdefghijklmop-qrstuvwxy--z")', 
... setup='import re; r=re.compile(r"^(?!.*--)[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,13}[a-z0-9]$")')
0.5857406334929749
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='r.match("a-bcdefghijklmop-qrstuvwxy--z")', 
... setup='import re; r=re.compile(r"^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]|-(?!-)){0,13}[a-z0-9]$")')
2.2273210211646415
```

So the `(?!.*--)` is a tiny bit slower in its worst case scenario (`--` early in the string, therefore lots of backtracking), but it's four times faster in its best case scenario (`--` late in the string, so nearly no backtracking).

Comment: I'm not very keen on using negative lookahead assertions with the `*` quantifier in.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Can I (perhaps naively) ask why?

Comment: @ean: I suspect that they're expensive and they certainly don't match how I think. I like my assertions to have a very strictly bounded number of characters that must be searched.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Sounds reasonable. In this case, couldn't the `*` be omitted and still have the desired effect?

Comment: @ean5533: In this case, you cannot omit .* because the "--" can occur anywhere in the 15-length string.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Your suspicion is incorrect, at least compared to my alternative solution. The alternation is killing you if `--` occurs late in the string (or if it doesn't occur at all). Perhaps you have a better idea for an alternative regex, though.

Comment: @Tim: Depends on the RE implementation; PCRE's stack-based which has one type of performance profile, but automata-based ones are totally different.

Comment: @DonalFellows: I hadn't thought of that. Are there automata-based regex engines that support lookahead?

Comment: @Tim: Yes; Henry Spencer's later ones.